# Apple Hardware Test gives no issues, but MacBook 8,1 fails to load after login

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, hardware, repair

This MacBook fails to finish logging in after boot ... diagnosis was a "bad harddrive cable", but after replacing that, no change. For reference, an independent, Apple-certified repair center did a "long" diagnostic after the "Genius" (term used only due to branding) bar said the hard drive was bad.

The laptop boots to a login prompt. After successful login, a progress bar that looks like a firmware update or system check takes a long time to complete (>15 min), and then the computer shuts off. I'd like to reclaim the current OS install, and avoid reformatting/reinstalling.

How can I diagnose what is wrong, without being able to login? AHT "long" test shows no problems.

Bonus points: how can I run the same diagnostics the Apple-Certified repair center did, so I can see the error codes, etc...

Update:
Disk Utility in repair mode failed to verify or repair the disk.
`Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting`
`Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map`

Comment: Why didn't you have the Apple-certified repair center fix the problem?  Did they try swapping the HD for a good one to verify the original findings of Apple?

Comment: They wouldn’t repair it, cited it being “vintage”.  I don’t know what other steps they tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this was a dying (very almost dead) hard drive. Replacing the drive solved the major issues, although there is still a [progress bar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325357/what-is-this-progress-bar-after-initial-boot-before-login-on-high-sierra) open.

This answer is simply to mark the question 'resolved/closed'.

Answer (score 0):

- Run Disk Utitiy from Recovery Mode. On Reboot, press Command (⌘) R. Open Disk Utility. Your partition map might be corrupt. Hit repair a couple of times.
- Reset NVRAM/PRAM.  http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761
- Also run EtreCheck and post the report here. Free Download:
  http://etresoft.com/etrecheck.

Answer (score -2):

It may well be a disk failure. I would try "FirstAid" in DiskUtility on the disk first and then on the bootpartition.

Comment: Your answer was given six hours after the information in the original question indicated that both verify and repair failed.