# What is this progress bar, after initial boot, before login, on High Sierra?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, high-sierra, ssd

This progress bar shows up after POST (and initial firmware boot?), but before the login prompt. The drive is a brand new SSD (from WD and initialized properly), so I'm really doubtful it's an fsck issue. The OS is a brand new High Sierra install, and showed up both before and after updates.

This is not a firmware or other update bar - I've seen those during the updates and there is an annotation to indicate those bars' sources. I have already reset the PRAM/NVRAM.

What is causing this progress bar? (I'm concerned, as the previous drive failed after this sort of bar began showing up, and the same bar is showing up on a MacBook Air during the same phase of startup...)

[image: progress bar]

Comment: It the "loading" progress bar.  Boot in Verbose mode (Cmd-V) to see what it's hiding.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, I’ll take a look at that next time I boot the computer...

Comment: Okay, so that scrolled way to fast for me to get more than a few glimpses and nothing stood out - is there a way to pause or pipe the output to a file for review?

Comment: Right after you boot, enter the Terminal command `sudo dmesg`

Comment: Thanks @Allan, now what should I be looking for? There are no obvious errors, but a lot of messages about IOAudioEngine. Is there a standard SE-approved site to used for log dumps, or is pastebin the standard? Also, it looks like the top line got cut off - does the ‘dmesg’ command just tail the dmesg log?